# Correcting Form Error

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make it so that if the user does not enter their first and last name an alert message will occur. The code looks right to me but it is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function func(){
        var first = getElementByID("fname").value;
        var last = getElementByID("lname").value;
        var email = getElementByID("mail").value;
        var phone = getElementByID("phone").value;
if ( first == "" && last =="")
            {
                    alert("Please Enter First and Last Name");


            }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="survey" name="survey" method="post">
        First Name:<br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
        Last Name:<br>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
        Email:<br>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail"><br>
        Phone Number:<br>
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" onclick="func()">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. use `document.getElementById`, not `getElementByID`
2. The `if` should use `||` (OR), not `&&` (AND), so it alerts if either field is empty, not only when both fields are empty.
3. To keep the form from submitting, the validation function must return `false`, and the `onclick` attribute needs to return the value.
4. It's better to use the form's `onsubmit` handler than the submit button's `onclick` handler.

So the JS should be:

```
function func(){
    var first = getElementByID("fname").value;
    var last = getElementByID("lname").value;
    var email = getElementByID("mail").value;
    var phone = getElementByID("phone").value;
    if ( first == "" && last =="") {
        alert("Please Enter First and Last Name");
        return false;
    }
}
```

and the HTML should be:

```
<form id="survey" name="survey" method="post" onsubmit="return func()">
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail"><br>
    Phone Number:<br>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"><br><br>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( first == "" && last =="")
```

implies that the warning will appear *only* if first AND last are empty.
Try using:

```
if ( first == "" || last =="")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use **document.getElementById('fname')**, not getElementByID
2. error in your condition, try it with (first == "" **||** last == "")
   (first is empty OR last is empty) -> error

**EDIT**, code snippet, in your code, there is missing one **}** at the end of script!

```js
function func(){
  var first = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var last = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("mail").value;
  var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  if ( first == "" || last =="")
  {
    alert("Please Enter First and Last Name");
    return false;
  }
  
  return true;
 }
```

```html
<form id="survey" name="survey" method="post" onsubmit="return func();">
        First Name:<br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
        Last Name:<br>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
        Email:<br>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail"><br>
        Phone Number:<br>
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: ok I made the changes, but no alert box is popping up when I click submit